# Is there a overview of all buckminster commands for the hudson buckminster plugin?

Tags: eclipse, hudson, eclipse-pde, buckminster

I am trying to set up a continous build of our PDE project using hudson + buckminster.

The problem i got is, i can't find any list/documentation of the available commands. I think it should be the headless buckminster commands, unfortunately i can't find them documented either.

**Anybody got an overview of the available commands? Maybe we should use this question to collect them all? Thanks :)**

(I am specially looking for resolving a query,the materialization of the workspace and invoking the p2 update site action)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [discussion](http://markmail.org/message/jrrebbwu23yujuak):

> The commands available depends on your configuration since the features you include will add new commands dynamically. You can always obtain a full list by entering:
>
> buckminster lscmds

Answer (score 0):

The Buckminster Book available from buckminster downloads has documentation for all of the commands provided by the buckminster project.